# how to scroll single image in xna 4.0?

Tags: xna, xnanimation

I want to scroll single image on touch like in angry birds.
can i use any gestures for scroll single image? And without using gestures how to scroll image?
Please help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pinchgesturesrecognizer to scroll an image. here is code.

```
 UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGesture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc]   
 initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scaleImage:)];
 [self.view addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];

 - (void)scaleImage:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
 {

 if([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

    previousScale = 1.0;
    return;
 }

  CGFloat newScale = 1.0 - (previousScale - [recognizer scale]);
  CGAffineTransform currentTransformation = yourimage.transform;
  CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(currentTransformation, newScale, newScale);
  yourimage.transform = newTransform;
  previousScale = [recognizer scale];
}
```